# Python: SQL Alchemy Create Engine Syntax Issues

Tags: python, sql-server, connection

Let's say I have the following connection information for a MSSQL server:

```
 'Driver={SQL Server};' 
 'Server=VCAB18RPACRGZ12\GNRSRZ11,1414;' 
 'Database=sampleDB;' 
 'uid=sampleID;' 
 'pwd=samplePW'
```

I want to write a python dataframe to the MSSQL server as a table.  I have the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

connection = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://sampleID:samplePW@myhost:VCAB18RPACRGZ12\GNRSRZ11,1414/sampleDB?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+10.0')
```

My above connection code is erroring out.  I'm not sure exactly where my connection information is supposed to go in the create_engine statement.

This is my error ...

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
>    'VCAB18RPACRGZ12\GNRSRZ11,1414'

Answer (score 0):

> Your Server Address is not correct.
>   If **1414** is the port#, you should use "**:**" instead of "*,*".

The **SQLAlchemy** uses pyodbc as the default DBAPI. pymssql is also available.
Below is the connection string sample:

```
# pyodbc -DSN
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger@mydsn')

# pymssql
engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://scott:tiger@hostname:port/dbname')

# pyodbc -DSN Less connection
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
#assumes driver name=[SQL+Server+Native+Client+10.0]
#engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://username:password@hostname:port/databasename?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+10.0')

engine = create_engine(r'mssql+pyodbc://sampleID:samplePW@VCAB18RPACRGZ12\GNRSRZ11:1414/sampleDB?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+10.0')
print engine
```

Comment: thank you; can you show me exactly what the syntax should be for the engine given my information?  I have seen your high level examples before...now it is a matter of getting the exact syntax down which is what I'm struggling with